# Xamarin Android app 504 error

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I just went live with my android app (Xamarin) -- and all my users are getting a -504 error when they try to install the application. Please help!

The app name is 'ControlTower' (the one with a tick symbol); can you tell me what I might have done wrong

Answer (score 0):

Seems to download fine here. So I don't know who "all your users" are, but they might want to check this link: http://appslova.com/fix-android-504-error/

> The error 504 code appears while attempting to download apps or games
>   in the Google Play Store. This is a gateway timeout error and is
>   generally associated with slower internet connections or mobile data
>   networks. Simple fix that worked for some is turning your mobile data
>   off and then back on. You can try it now by turning your Airplane mode
>   on and then off or by going to settings >> data usage>> turn off
>   Mobile data and turn it back on. Now try to download or update the app
>   via Google Play. If that didn’t work, some users have even solved the
>   Google Play Store error 504  by freeing some space in their android
>   device by uninstalling unwanted apps or games.  If these Android fixes
>   didn’t work there are more to go in this post for “App” could not be
>   downloaded due to an error. (504)

Has more to do with the user's device than anything else. You say it just went live. It might have to fall through to all proxies and servers etc. So it might just be a small hiccup while going live on the app store.